# Tags from fork are shown in main repository

Tags: github, git-fork, git-tag

I am working on mod for FOSS game and the author of game that I forked asked me why tags from my fork appeared in his repo.

Why this happened?

[image: my repo] [image: his repo]

my tags are one without `v`

Comment: Which tags are those? We cannot tell from the screenshot which tags you orginally cloned along with the repo, and which you added later.

Comment: If neither you nor he added those tags to *his* GitHub fork, then only GitHub themselves could have done that. You'd have to ask them (not Git) why.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.